# Facebook API GraphAPIError active access token must be used

Tags: python, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get some User information via Ajax(RPC) call from my facebook canvas application.

Since I am using facebook API for python, I get the signed_request first:

```
signed_request = utility.parse_signed_request(self.request.get('signed_request'),FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
```

I exchange the token and I put the access token in current session:

```
def get_long_lived_access_token(self, EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN):
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    url += FACEBOOK_APP_ID
    url += "&client_secret="
    url += FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
    url += "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="
    url += EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    self.session['oauth_token'] = response
```

If I make a call to facebook API(with access token before exchange):

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(signed_request['oauth_token'])
me = graph.get_object("me")
```

It works very well, but if I try to create the graph during the Ajax call (both with short lived exchanged access tokens):

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(self.session['oauth_token'])
me = graph.get_object("me")
```

It gives me an error:

```
GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I also checked the exchanged access token validity in https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
and it was a valid access token.

How should I have access to users the graph objects during my Ajax calls?

Comment: Have you verified if `self.session['oauth_token']` contains the correct value at that point?

Comment: yes, I write that value and the tested it in graph.facebook.com.

Comment: After that it worked well, I actually forget about using get_object and called the graph directly using the access token and made a workaround for the problem which is already working.